# Appending joins

Tags: mysql, join

I have been working on a website that shows a ratings ladder, it processes all the matches that players play.

What I have at the moment is the following table, but when I want to select all the matches of a player I have to include "or" statements and also have indexes for all the columns that have the player names. So I have designed a new approach.

**[Current Method]**

aoe3_sp_games Table

Info: Holds all the matches ever played and the players relating to it.

```
Column  Type    Null    Default
game_id char(36)    No          
map varchar(30) No          
date_time   int(11) No          
length  float   No          
player_count    tinyint(4)  No          
t1_p1   varchar(16) No          
t1_p2   varchar(16) No          
t1_p3   varchar(16) No          
t1_p4   varchar(16) No          
t2_p1   varchar(16) No          
t2_p2   varchar(16) No          
t2_p3   varchar(16) No          
t2_p4   varchar(16) No          
t1_p1_rating    smallint(4) No          
t1_p2_rating    smallint(4) No          
t1_p3_rating    smallint(4) No          
t1_p4_rating    smallint(4) No          
t2_p1_rating    smallint(4) No          
t2_p2_rating    smallint(4) No          
t2_p3_rating    smallint(4) No          
t2_p4_rating    smallint(4) No          
t1_p1_pr    float(6,2)  No          
t1_p2_pr    float(6,2)  No          
t1_p3_pr    float(6,2)  No          
t1_p4_pr    float(6,2)  No          
t2_p1_pr    float(6,2)  No          
t2_p2_pr    float(6,2)  No          
t2_p3_pr    float(6,2)  No          
t2_p4_pr    float(6,2)  No          
t1_p1_civ   char(2) No          
t1_p2_civ   char(2) No          
t1_p3_civ   char(2) No          
t1_p4_civ   char(2) No          
t2_p1_civ   char(2) No          
t2_p2_civ   char(2) No          
t2_p3_civ   char(2) No          
t2_p4_civ   char(2) No
```

**[New Method]**

aoe3_sp_matches Table

Info: Holds all the matches ever played.

```
Column  Type    Null    Default
match_id    int(10) No          
match_guid  char(36)    No          
map varchar(30) No          
date_time   int(11) No          
length  float   No          
player_count    tinyint(4)  No
```

aoe3_sp_match_players Table

Info: Holds all the players that are relating to the matches from the #Matches_table.

```
Column  Type    Null    Default Links to
match_id    int(10) No      aoe3_sp_matches -> match_id     
player_id   int(10) No      eso_players -> player_id        
team    tinyint(4)  No              
player_name varchar(16) No              
player_rating   smallint(4) No              
player_pr   float(6,2)  Yes NULL            
player_civ  char(2) No
```

What I need is to get all the matches a player has played using the #Match_Players_table.
Then join the match ids to the players involved in the match.

Any match can only have a max number of 8 players(4vs4) and a minimum of 2(1vs1) players.

I am using Player 1570 for tests, as he looks ideal for the situation with not too many matches played.

I have read somewhere not to use no more than 2 joins or it can be bad on performance.
My website processes around 5000~ matches for 3 days and 17000~ rows for players who played them, these numbers are based on the New Method.

My mysql version is: 5.1.61.

***My website***: http://exciple.com/forum/player.php?n=yosimasa&s=m

***SQL Fiddle***: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b2245/3

---

**Result type one**

Basically combining all the players that belonged to that match on one row with the info of the match, just like method one. I did try to get results like this, but I struggle with joins more than one that append to a row. I understand this would require many joins, so not the ideal way to do it.

```
game_id map date_time   length  player_count    t1_p1   t1_p2   t1_p3   t1_p4   t2_p1   t2_p2   t2_p3   t2_p4   t1_p1_rating    t1_p2_rating    t1_p3_rating    t1_p4_rating    t2_p1_rating    t2_p2_rating    t2_p3_rating    t2_p4_rating    t1_p1_pr    t1_p2_pr    t1_p3_pr    t1_p4_pr    t2_p1_pr    t2_p2_pr    t2_p3_pr    t2_p4_pr    t1_p1_civ   t1_p2_civ   t1_p3_civ   t1_p4_civ   t2_p1_civ   t2_p2_civ   t2_p3_civ   t2_p4_civ
    43f9499f-870d-47c0-8a05-47554e349698    great plains    1413510540  1451    4   greenandugly    Jomp17          Armykid913  FUHAHAHA            1616    1616    0   0   1584    1571    0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    FR  OT          OT  BR
```

**Result type two**

So I have been messing around with queries and here is what I got to so far.

Execute two queries

*[One for games]*

```
SELECT aoe3_sp_matches.* FROM aoe3_sp_matches
right JOIN `aoe3_sp_match_players`
ON `aoe3_sp_match_players`.`match_id`=`aoe3_sp_matches`.`match_id`
WHERE player_id = 1570
```

Returns all the games of the player 1570. This works fine.

*[Second one for players of the matches]*

```
SELECT aoe3_sp_match_players.* FROM aoe3_sp_match_players
right JOIN `aoe3_sp_matches`
ON `aoe3_sp_match_players`.`match_id`=`aoe3_sp_matches`.`match_id`
WHERE aoe3_sp_match_players.player_id = 1570
```

Returns the data from aoe3_sp_match_players that meets with the where clause. Does not return all the players but only the one from the where clause.

```
SELECT aoe3_sp_match_players.* FROM aoe3_sp_match_players
WHERE aoe3_sp_match_players.match_id in 
    (SELECT aoe3_sp_match_players.match_id
        FROM  aoe3_sp_match_players
        WHERE player_id = 1570)
```

I managed to get the data the way I wanted but with a subquery and it is slower than the joins on my DB, not a surprize there.

***EDIT:*** I found a way to get the second part of result type two using a join on the outside, it is as fast as a join placed before the where clause.

```
Select
  aoe3_sp_match_players.match_id,
  aoe3_sp_match_players.team,
  aoe3_sp_match_players.player_name,
  aoe3_sp_match_players.player_rating,
  aoe3_sp_match_players.player_pr,
  aoe3_sp_match_players.player_civ
From
  (Select
    aoe3_sp_match_players.match_id
  From
    aoe3_sp_match_players
  Where
    aoe3_sp_match_players.player_id = 1570
  Limit 30) aoe3_sp_matches Left Join
  aoe3_sp_match_players On aoe3_sp_match_players.match_id =
    aoe3_sp_matches.match_id
Order By
  aoe3_sp_match_players.match_id Desc
```

What do you reckon is the best way to get the results?

Comment: Have you ever written a working `JOIN`?

Comment: Yeah a basic one: SELECT `aoe3_sp_civs_overall`.`player_id`, `aoe3_sp_civs_overall`.`BR_used`, `aoe3_sp_overall`.`rating`
FROM `aoe3_sp_overall`
INNER JOIN `aoe3_sp_civs_overall`
ON `aoe3_sp_civs_overall`.`player_id`=`aoe3_sp_overall`.`player_id`
ORDER BY `aoe3_sp_overall`.`rating` DESC LIMIT 0,30;

Comment: Obviously it's better to use normalized tables.  You are not yet there. You need to have in **Players** only the information about the players themselves and then create a separate "*link*" table **PlayersInMatches** where you will match (no pan intended) `player_id` with `match_id`. So three tables altogether that will require two simple `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: I already have the players table, I left this table to the last to normalize as it is quite large. Also I included the player name in the matches table not to add another join. The whole database layout: [link](http://exciple.com/phpMyAdmin.pdf)

Comment: I told you how your tables should be organized. Then queries will become simple and clear. If you want to suffer, it's your right.

Comment: **I included the player name in the matches table not to add another join** that's wrong I'm afraid, do NOT be frightened of joins, DO be frightened of **redundant data**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with this setup. Your new approach is definitely better than the last one but it still needs some working around. You're on the right track though.

Do you have a limit for the amount of players allowed for every match? It seems like your old method allowed for a maximum of 4 players per match. In your new method, you can have any number of players per match, which may or may not be what you intend.

The result you're expecting can only be achieved if you enforce in your application somehow that a maximum of four players can share a match. This isn't desired though, because your data integrity now depends on the application layer and not just the database.

Without taking into account all these things that I mentioned, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    game.match_id,
    game.match_guid,
    game.map,
    game.date_time,
    game.length,
    game.player_count,

    team1_player1.player_name,
    team1_player1.player_rating,
    team1_player1.player_pr,
    team1_player1.player_civ,
    team1_player2.player_name,
    team1_player2.player_rating,
    team1_player2.player_pr,
    team1_player2.player_civ,
    team1_player3.player_name,
    team1_player3.player_rating,
    team1_player3.player_pr,
    team1_player3.player_civ,
    team1_player4.player_name,
    team1_player4.player_rating,
    team1_player4.player_pr,
    team1_player4.player_civ,
    team2_player1.player_name,
    team2_player1.player_rating,
    team2_player1.player_pr,
    team2_player1.player_civ,
    team2_player2.player_name,
    team2_player2.player_rating,
    team2_player2.player_pr,
    team2_player2.player_civ,
    team2_player3.player_name,
    team2_player3.player_rating,
    team2_player3.player_pr,
    team2_player3.player_civ,
    team2_player4.player_name,
    team2_player4.player_rating,
    team2_player4.player_pr,
    team2_player4.player_civ
FROM 
    matches_table as game
    LEFT JOIN match_players as team1_player1 ON game.match_id = team1_player1.match_id and team1_player1.player_id = 1
    LEFT JOIN match_players as team1_player2 ON game.match_id = team1_player2.match_id and team1_player1.player_id = 2
    LEFT JOIN match_players as team1_player3 ON game.match_id = team1_player3.match_id and team1_player1.player_id = 3
    LEFT JOIN match_players as team1_player4 ON game.match_id = team1_player4.match_id and team1_player1.player_id = 4
    LEFT JOIN match_players as team2_player1 ON game.match_id = team2_player1.match_id and team1_player1.player_id = 5
    LEFT JOIN match_players as team2_player2 ON game.match_id = team2_player2.match_id and team1_player1.player_id = 6
    LEFT JOIN match_players as team2_player3 ON game.match_id = team2_player3.match_id and team1_player1.player_id = 7
    LEFT JOIN match_players as team2_player4 ON game.match_id = team2_player4.match_id and team1_player1.player_id = 8
```

You would have to know the ids of the players previously. Also, a player can only be attached to one single match. That value would have to change for a new match and we loose history of any previous matches the player was in. That was to illustrate that it can be done, and also how ugly it can get. I do not recommend proceeding this way.

Do notice though, that you can join the same table several times. This can be really helpful, since you need information from many records condensed into one.

---

**SOLUTION:**

You can have a table for games, a table for players and create a third table for matches:

**Games**

```
game_id
map
//other columns with info about this map. you could also name the table maps
```

**Players**

```
player_id
player_name
player_pr
player_civ
```

**Matches**

```
match_id
map
date_time
team1_player1
team1_player2
team2_player1
team2_player2
```

this last table contains the ids of the players. an output could look like this:

```
match_id  map              team1_player1  team1_player2  team2_player1  team2_player2
1         great plains     0001           0002           0003           0004
```

You can also use usernames as ids, just be sure they're unique (primary key)

The resulting SQL query would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    games.map,
    matches.match_id,
    matches.date_time,

    team1_player1.player_name,
    team1_player1.player_rating,
    team1_player1.player_pr,
    team1_player1.player_civ,
    team1_player2.player_name,
    team1_player2.player_rating,
    team1_player2.player_pr,
    team1_player2.player_civ,
    team1_player3.player_name,
    team1_player3.player_rating,
    team1_player3.player_pr,
    team1_player3.player_civ,
    team1_player4.player_name,
    team1_player4.player_rating,
    team1_player4.player_pr,
    team1_player4.player_civ,
    team2_player1.player_name,
    team2_player1.player_rating,
    team2_player1.player_pr,
    team2_player1.player_civ,
    team2_player2.player_name,
    team2_player2.player_rating,
    team2_player2.player_pr,
    team2_player2.player_civ,
    team2_player3.player_name,
    team2_player3.player_rating,
    team2_player3.player_pr,
    team2_player3.player_civ,
    team2_player4.player_name,
    team2_player4.player_rating,
    team2_player4.player_pr,
    team2_player4.player_civ
FROM 
    games
    INNER JOIN matches ON matches.map = games.map
    INNER JOIN match_players as team1_player1 ON team1_player1.player_id = matches.team1_player1
    INNER JOIN match_players as team1_player2 ON team1_player1.player_id = matches.team1_player2
    INNER JOIN match_players as team1_player3 ON team1_player1.player_id = matches.team1_player3
    INNER JOIN match_players as team1_player4 ON team1_player1.player_id = matches.team1_player4
    INNER JOIN match_players as team2_player1 ON team1_player1.player_id = matches.team2_player1
    INNER JOIN match_players as team2_player2 ON team1_player1.player_id = matches.team2_player2
    INNER JOIN match_players as team2_player3 ON team1_player1.player_id = matches.team2_player3
    INNER JOIN match_players as team2_player4 ON team1_player1.player_id = matches.team2_player4
```

With this approach, your players table contains information only about the players, and nothing about the match. You keep history of every match a player has been in and you also separate maps and other information relevant to the game separate from the match itself. The  matches table only ties everything together. Also, the player number restriction comes back to the database and is application independent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: And when you decide that having a limit of 4 players per game is killing your business you would need to completely redesign the database again. Of course you need to enforce the limit in the application, some games may have a limit of 2 others 4 and in the future some may have no limit... so don't design the database in a limited manner.

Comment: Well yes, but my answer was oriented to what the person asking already has and wants. It's not how I would do it, but it answers the question. He wants the result in a single row.